# Google App Engine update version

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I get the following error and can't figure it out(tried unrarring python-egg files,but nothing change)
This error happened right after 1.76 update, then i installed older version 1.75, but yesterday it begun to give me strange error, that something's deprecated etc., so i figured since it's "five" updates from 1.75, everything should be fine ... and it isn't.
Any comments appreciated :

```
2013-06-02 22:20:20 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\python.exe', 'C:\\Program Files     (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--    port=8082', '--admin_port=8002', 'E:\\Dropbox\\GAE\\ajaxtest\\ajaxtest']"
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyyaml-3.10-py2.7-win32.egg\_yaml.py:3: UserWarning: Module yaml was already imported from C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\yaml-3.10\yaml\__init__.py, but c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pyyaml-3.10-py2.7-win32.egg is being added to sys.path
INFO     2013-06-02 22:20:21,775 devappserver2.py:522] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2013-06-02 22:20:21,815 api_server.py:153] Starting API server at: http://localhost:55511
INFO     2013-06-02 22:20:21,818 dispatcher.py:164] Starting server "default" running at: http://localhost:8082
INFO     2013-06-02 22:20:21,819 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8002
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyyaml-3.10-py2.7-win32.egg\_yaml.py:3: UserWarning: Module yaml was already imported from C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\yaml-3.10\yaml\__init__.py, but c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pyyaml-3.10-py2.7-win32.egg is being added to sys.path

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\_python_runtime.py", line 182, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\_python_runtime.py", line 178, in _run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\runtime.py", line 29, in <module>
    from google.appengine.ext.remote_api import remote_api_stub
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\remote_api\remote_api_stub.py", line 75, in <module>
    import yaml
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\yaml-3.10\yaml\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from cyaml import *
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\yaml-3.10\yaml\cyaml.py", line 5, in <module>
    from _yaml import CParser, CEmitter
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyyaml-3.10-py2.7-win32.egg\_yaml.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyyaml-3.10-py2.7-win32.egg\_yaml.py", line 4, in __bootstrap__
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.45-py2.7.egg\pkg_resources.py", line 914, in resource_filename
    self, resource_name
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.45-py2.7.egg\pkg_resources.py", line 1423, in get_resource_filename


 self._extract_resource(manager, self._eager_to_zip(name))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.45-py2.7.egg\pkg_resources.py", line 1479, in _extract_resource
    manager.extraction_error()  # report a user-friendly error
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.45-py2.7.egg\pkg_resources.py", line 960, in extraction_error
    raise err
pkg_resources.ExtractionError: Can't extract file(s) to egg cache

The following error occurred while trying to extract file(s) to the Python egg
cache:

  [Error 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\HAL\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python-Eggs\\pyyaml-3.10-py2.7-win32.egg-tmp\\_yaml.pyd'

The Python egg cache directory is currently set to:

  C:\Users\HAL\AppData\Roaming\Python-Eggs

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  You can
change the cache directory by setting the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment
variable to point to an accessible directory.

ERROR    2013-06-02 22:20:22,275 http_runtime.py:221] unexpected port response from runtime ['']; exiting the development server
INFO     2013-06-02 22:20:22,838 api_server.py:524] Applying all pending transactions and saving the datastore
INFO     2013-06-02 22:20:22,838 api_server.py:527] Saving search indexes
2013-06-02 22:20:22 (Process exited with code 0)
```

Comment: Why not installing the latest which is the 1.8.0? There is no point of running older versions.. and there will be deprecated stuff.. always try to be on the latest version with the backend..

Comment: This error comes with 1.8, sorry for not pointing it out.

Comment: What errors? You should try to resolve these errors instead of trying to install older versions that also have errors..! Which version of Python do you have?

Comment: Not sure i understand the part "What errors?You should try to resolve these errors.." 
Python version is 2.7. I tried resolving Python-Egg problem, after 1.7.6 version, but couldn't find anything that helped me or worked for me (Win7). So i need to work anyway, that's the reason i have downgraded back to 1.7.5, because to be honest, on my development machine it is VERY rare case, that you update your development environment and it's all crazy now, rainbows and unicorns, pink clouds etc., usually it is just no influence on my work, unless there's some errors or similar things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there something that you require out of an egg? If not, change (or unset) `PYTHON_EGG_CACHE` to get the egg mechanism out of the way. We don't ship or package anything App Engine-related that requires eggs.

Comment: No, i do not need anything from egg. Having hard time changing the directory, tried, but it didn't worked:
import os

os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = 'C:/tmp'

Comment: I'll try to reinstall everything and avoid setup tools and python egg at all if possible.

Comment: It worked, removed all python related and reinstalling Python 2.7.5, now everything's back to place.